# Find the missing number in the given array of numbers using PHP

Tags: php

Am new to php i have faced an interview some days ago, and the interviewer asked a question like the following one.

The given array has 99 numbers, which contains the digits from 1 to 100
with one digit missing. Describe two different algorithms that finds you the missing number.  The algorithm should optimize for low storage and fast processing. Output should show the execution time of each algorithm.

And i have searched google about it, and come to know its a common puzzle used to ask in interviews. I found out the answer like this way.

```
int sum = 0;
int idx = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 0) {
         idx = i; 
    } else {
         sum += arr[i];
    }
}

// the total sum of numbers between 1 and arr.length.
int total = (arr.length + 1) * arr.length / 2;

System.out.println("missing number is: " + (total - sum) + " at index " + idx);
```

But the code is not in php,

Can u please help me to find out the php code and algorithm name. So i can improve my answer in the next interviews.

Comment: Did you try converting that Java code into PHP? It should be fairly straight forward, when it says `arr.length` use `count($arr)`, the rest should be pretty much the same.

Answer (score 9):

In PHP you can easily use some array functions and achieve that. Best way is,

```
$missing = array_diff(range(1,100),$array);
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZzIqT2)**.

Comment: Thank you so much for this quick reply. Did u know any proper
algorithm is there to calculate this one?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by *proper algorithm* ?

Comment: @user3480508 if you try to find an element which is missing within the array this is the shortest way to do it. But if you are looking for time complexity its same as linear/sequential search with O(n) as the time complexity. If you know the element needed to be searched u can apply other good algo like binary search / interpolation search etc which are far better in terms of complexity .

Comment: `array_diff` is the best approach because it doesn't presume that the two arrays being compared will be in an ordered, consecutive set. Most data won't be missing one member of the larger set, nor will the larger set likely be one that can be created through `range()`. The other approaches are clever but are very confined to those unlikely parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is by using the array_sum function and the knowledge that all numbers from 1 to 100 added together equals 5050.

```
$missing = 5050-array_sum($array);
```

Comment: or just use `range` to get 5050 : `$missing = array_sum(range(1,100)) - array_sum($array);`

Answer (score 0):

Converted to PHP, it is nearly the same.
(Not tested)

Of course, there are better ways, like the one **Rikesh** posted, but this is the exact one you asked for:

```
$sum = 0
$idx = -1
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
   if($arr[$i] == 0){
      $idx = $i;
   }else{
      $sum += $arr[$i];
   }
}

$total = (count($arr) + 1) * (count($arr) / 2);

echo "Missing: " . ($total - $sum) . " at index " . $idx;
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, **Keir**. I must have missed this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr=range(1,99);
$j=1;
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
if(!in_array($j,$arr)){
    echo $j.'is missing';
}
$j++;
}
```